# css3 media queries: iPad overwrite iphone4 (retina) rules

Tags: css, safari, mobile-safari

Seems that iPad rules overwrite iPhone4 related rules.
How can I solve this problem?

```
/* iPad */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {
    #theDiv { width: 400px; }
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    #theDiv { width: 600px; }    
}


/* iPhoneRetina */
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
    #theDiv { width: 200px; }
}
```

Comment: Did you set the viewport to width=device-width ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bump the Retina display's pixel ratio to 2.

[Here's the link to the Webkit blog post about it](http://www.webkit.org/blog/55/high-dpi-web-sites/).  Go down to the header "Conditional Inclusion".